# How can I implement KFunctionN in Kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

If I define

```
class MyF : KFunction0<Int> {
    override val name: String = "f"
    override fun invoke() = 42

    override val annotations: List<Annotation>
        get() = TODO()
    ....
}
```

I can write

```
val f0: KFunction0<Int> = MyF()
assertEquals("f", f0.name)
```

but if I try

```
assertEquals(42, f0())
```

I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: MyF cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0`

How can I define my own implementation of `KFunction0`?

I can't work with `() -> Int` because I need the `name` property.

I'm using Kotlin 1.3.21.

Additionally - it seems that I can run

```
val f02 = MyF()
assertEquals(42, f02())
```

My actual use case is [Can I convert a Kotlin KFunction1 to a KFunction0 by applying the argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650207/can-i-convert-a-kotlin-kfunction1-to-a-kfunction0-by-applying-the-argument)

Comment: whitch kotlin version do you use?

Comment: According to https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md both `kotlin.FunctionN` and `kotlin.reflect.KFunctionN` are "fictitious, which means they have no sources and no runtime representation". I'd expect your use case needs that missing runtime representation.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely not a good idea to explicitly implement an internal class from Kotlin JVM. You do not have code completion for that classes in IntelliJ or Android Studio for a reason

You may use callable references instead, to make Kotlin compiler generate all necessary classes for you.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references

```
    fun myfun() = 42
    val kFunction = ::myfun


    println(kFunction.name)
    println(kFunction())
```

The benefit - future version of Kotlin will unlikely to break that code (and may break you inheritor class)

Should you need a longer name for the function, you may declare it like that

```
fun `my function with long name`() = 43
```

Comment: But the type of `kFunction` in your example is `KFunction0<Int>`. I can assign it to `() -> Int`, but then I loose the `.name` property, which is unfortunately necessary to my use case.

Comment: It is fine to use the type, yes it is `KFunction0<Int>`. The good is you do not need to implement the type manually in your code

Comment: I have a use-case where I want to convert a KFunction1 to a KFunction0 by applying the parameter. I'm coming to the conclusion that isn't a thing that I can do!

Comment: Partial application is possible. You may just declare a function for partial application and use it for the :: reference. Hence, the name would not be the original function.

Another approach - create your own classes/interfaces
```
data class MyFunction1<T, R>(val name: String, val f: (T) -> R) {
  operator fun invoke(t: T) = f(t)
}
data class MyFunction0<R>(val name: String, val f: () -> R) {
  operator fun invoke() = f()
}
```
Now define the curring: 
```
fun MyFunction1<T, R>.curry(t: T) = MyFunction0(name){ f(t) }
(it can be a member function too)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin 1.2 I haven't found `KFunction0<T>` but only `KFunction<T>` and I was able to do what you wanted:

```
import kotlin.reflect.*
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class MyKF : KFunction<Int>{ // In Kotlin 1.3 you can extend KFunction0<Int>

    override val annotations: List<Annotation>
        get() = listOf()
    override val isAbstract: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isExternal: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isFinal: Boolean
        get() = true
    override val isInfix: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isInline: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isOpen: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isOperator: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val isSuspend: Boolean
        get() = false
    override val parameters: List<KParameter>
        get() = listOf()
    override val typeParameters: List<KTypeParameter>
        get() = listOf()

    /**
     * I am not sure how get proper return type. So... This KFunction will return kotlin.Number.
     */
    override val returnType: KType
        get() = Int::class.supertypes[0]
    override val visibility: KVisibility?
        get() = KVisibility.PUBLIC

    override fun call(vararg args: Any?): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun callBy(args: Map<KParameter, Any?>): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override val name: String
        get() = "f"

    // Sience Kotlin 1.3
    override fun invoke(): Int {
        return 0
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val kf = MyKF()
    assertEquals("f", kf.name)
    assertEquals(0, kf.call())

    println(kf.returnType)
    println(kf.name)
    println(kf.call())
    pritnln(kf.invoke())
}
```

I will update Kotlin to 1.3 later and I'll complete my answer (if it works in Kotlin 1.3).

**So where can be your problem? Maybe (just lucky guess) check type based on overriden methods like `returnType`?**

Edit:

After migrating to Kotlin 1.3 I was able to extend `KFunction0<Int>` instead of `KFunction<Int>`. The only changes - my class has to also override `invoke(): Int`. Still works!

Edit2:

I'm not sure if I just didn't saw KFunction0 in my IDE or is not present in Kotlin below 1.3.

Comment: You need to add the kotlin-reflection jar to see the KFunctionN's I believe. Your example works, but uses `call` rather than `invoke`

Comment: It is definitely not the best idea to implement that interface in your code explicitly. You may either create your own interface, or use callable references to force the compiler to do that for you

Comment: Nope, KFunction0 shows in Kotlin 1.3. @DuncanMcGregor I updated my answer. `KFunction0` exists and has method `invoke` ;)

Comment: An yep, I don't think it's the best idea to create code like this too, but I'm just answering the question :P

Comment: Have you tried running the final line (after making it `println` ;-)

Comment: Ah, more information. If you specify the type of kf - `val kf: KFunction0<Int> = MyKF()` it fails with a ClassCastException when you call `invoke`, but not when you invoice `call`

Comment: What do you mean by `final line`? You mean those assertions? Yep, I've tried and they didn't throw exception. Also, I tried make assertion like `assertEquals(0, kf())` (passed) and `assertEquals(1, kf())` (failed).

Comment: I figured that you could never have run the `pritnln` - so it might still ClassCastException. Now I see that it is the declared type of the reference that makes the difference.