# Can I convert a Kotlin KFunction1 to a KFunction0 by applying the argument?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have a reference to a functionthat needs a parameter.

```
fun foo(x: Int) = 2 * x
val f: KFunction1<Int, Int> = ::foo
```

Is there any way to write `applyArgument` where

```
val f2: KFunction0<Int> = f1.applyArgument(42) 
assertEquals("foo", f2.name)
assertEquals(84, f2())
```

I don't want to use a callable reference, as I need access to the `name` property.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54648917/97777

Answer (score 3):

hope it helps you:

```
fun foo(x: Int) = 2 * x
val f1 = ::foo
val f0 = { -> f1(42) }
f0() //84
```

Comment: I think that f0 is a callable reference here, and so does not have a `name` unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

`KFunction`s are intented to represent functions that are explicitly decleared in Kotlin code, but `f2` is not declared anywhere in the code. In addition `KFunction` has lot of reflection properties and functions which are not relevant to the applied function `f2`. Therefore even if it is possible it is not recommended.

If you want to do it anyway you can simply write an `applyArgument` function in this way:

```
fun <T, R> KFunction1<T, R>.applyArgument(value: T): KFunction0<R> {
    return object : KFunction<R> by this, KFunction0<R> {
        override fun invoke(): R {
            return this@applyArgument(value)
        }
    }
}
```

But, if what you need is to preserve the name, I would do it in a safe way. One way could be:

```
data class Named<out T>(val name: String, val value: T)

fun <T, R> Named<T>.map(transform: (T) -> R): Named<R> = Named(name, transform(value))

val <F : KFunction<*>> F.named: Named<F>
    get() = Named(name, this)
```

Then use it:

```
fun foo(x: Int) = 2 * x
val f: Named<(Int) -> Int> = ::foo.named

val f2: Named<() -> Int> = f.map { fValue -> { fValue(42) } }
assertEquals("foo", f2.name)
assertEquals(84, f2.value())
```

Comment: I had actually tried your first (and clever) solution, but it doesn't work because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648917/how-can-i-implement-kfunctionn-in-kotlin

Comment: You right. I have just tried to run it and it failed at run time. But it can be fixed like this: ``` fun <T, R> KFunction1<T, R>.applyArgument(value: T): KFunction0<R> { return object : KFunction<R> by this, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<R> { override fun invoke(): R { return this@applyArgument(value) } } as KFunction0<R> } ``

Answer (score 0):

Partial application is possible.

You may just declare a function for partial application and use it for the `::` reference.

Hence, the name would not be the original function. Another approach - create your own classes/interfaces

```
data class MyFunction1<T, R>(val name: String, val f: (T) -> R) { 
  operator fun invoke(t: T) = f(t) 
} 

data class MyFunction0<R>(val name: String, val f: () -> R) { 
  operator fun invoke() = f() 
}
```

Now define the curring:

```
fun MyFunction1<T, R>.curry(t: T) = MyFunction0(name){ f(t) }
```

(it can be a member function too)